# get an element by its class in angular

Tags: angularjs

I need to find the first element of class ngAggregate, with angular

I would like to find the equivalent in angular of :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ngAggregate')[0]; (which works)
```

However, I cannot use this as I need to do some binding later.

I tried that:

```
var aggregate =  angular.element('.ngAggregate')[0];
```

but I get en arror saying that angular.element('.ngAggregate') is undefined.

What is the correct method of writing ?

UPDATE:

```
var aggregate =  angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('ngAggregate')[0]);
```

does not return an error but I want to get the inside of "aggregate"

```
console.log(aggregate.childNodes[1].innerHTML);
```

I get

```
 Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

This is the complete error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/src/search/searchCtrl.js:377:49)
at j (http://localhost:8000/components/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2:27136)
at Object.k.add [as done] (http://localhost:8000/components/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2:27445)
at n.fn.ready (http://localhost:8000/components/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2:29551)
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/src/search/searchCtrl.js:370:35)
at invoke (http://localhost:8000/components/angular/angular.js:3720:17)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8000/components/angular/angular.js:3731:23)
at http://localhost:8000/components/angular/angular.js:6848:28
at updateView (http://localhost:8000/components/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js:2286:30)
at http://localhost:8000/components/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js:2234:9 <div ui-view="">
```

Comment: Do `angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('ngAggregate')[0])`

Comment: For your update, what `aggregate[0].childNodes[1].innerHTML` say?  Just debug and see what value `aggregate` returns? `aggregate` wont be DOM element it will be a jqLite wrapper over the DOM element.

Comment: OK PSL, I see your point, but is there a way for me to access the inner content ?

Comment: Did you read my previous comment? DId you try `console.log(aggregate.html())` and what it gives

Comment: console.log(aggregate.html()); gives me undefiend

Comment: Then it is not selecting any element, what is that element anyways?. Just debug to see if it selecting it and is part of the collection. WHat is that element anyways. If not please provide us a demo where you can replicate the issue. Also make sure you are doing this only after DOM has been rendered  by angular

Comment: Where is the answer?  Or why is it buried here in comments?  ;)